# Advantages of carrying sound via DisplayPort instead of direct sound card analog output?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, displayport, pulse-audio

I recently changed my monitor and the new one is connected to my computer via DisplayPort. This can also carry sound, and I can connect my speakers to the monitor instead of directly to the traditional analog output of the computer.

However I am not sure if there really is an increase in sound quality or general usefulness. Is there ?

I am asking because with the sound-via-Displayport setup I am experiencing the problem also described [on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/874320/audio-starts-playing-3-5-seconds-after-video-does) that whenever a sound starts, the first one or two seconds are not heard. I am wondering if it is worthwhile for me to invest time and energy into solving this problem or if I am better off just using the old-fashioned connection.

Comment: There are a few advantages to digital audio, as opposed to analog. DisplayPort uses digital audio which is less susceptible to noise introduced from other cables or RF emissions of electronic devices. I have a Dell laptop which did have a similar issue. I spent (wasted) alot of time trying to get to the bottom of it. In the end, it turned out that my Realtek audio drivers needed to be updated (reverted) (Windows 10, not Linux). My suggestion is check you drivers. If possible, use the ones that came with the hardware as opposed to the newest available.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was aware of interference problems with analog signals, but do they occur when the cable is less than 1.5 m and the output from the monitor (fed by DP) to the speaker is analog anyway ? I will also look into the drivers (testing a newer version for now).

Comment: It's really hard to say for sure. Most "good" cabling should be enough to shield from rf, but it depends on your environment. I would say that the "average" computer setup shouldn't have issues with rf, but some hardware, if damaged or poorly constructed could indeed leak rf quite badly. The FCC recently went after a guy in new York over his Bitcoin rig, which had nearly completely blocked major cellar network signals in his region...for example. In the end, it's really up to you. If you hook up with analog, and don't notice anything and are happy with that, then go with it.